# Why does Windows 8 plays a sound when I switch on an external light?

Tags: windows-8, system-sounds

I bought a new PC last week with Windows 8 on it. 
The PC is plugged into the master socket of a power strip. I also have a small lamp plugged into the same power strip.

**When I turn that lamp on or off, a sound is played on the Windows 8 PC!!!**

I could not figure out what sound is played exactly and there is no sound event named 'External device switched on' :-)

I guess switching on the light changes the power consumption in the power strip, but why would the PC and even the OS bother about this?

How can I turn this off?

The sound is not played every time I switch the light on or off, but on average every second time.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the PC can spot the difference in the running frequency from turning a domestic light on or off. Does the PC have any ambient light sensors that could be causing this?

Comment: No, no sensors except for a microphone on a USB headset but Speed Recognition is not turned on.

Comment: Custom build PC with a Asus P8H77-V board and a Core i7 3770 CPU. Sound on Board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure no USB devices are powered by this strip? Maybe a slight short/power drain is causing an external component to be re-detected.

**Update**

Because Peter has confirmed his printer was in "soft off" mode. I suspect that the turning on/off of the light caused the printer to recycle power internally, thus causing windows to detect a new USB device and making the device attached sound.

To resolve this issue, I would ensure both the power board and connectors are ok and for safety's sake, would replace the board with a new one to ensure the internal connectors can sustain reliable electrical contact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm having the same issue when turning of my amplifier which I use as a speaker for my computer. My keyboard sometimes goes off (and on) when turning the amplifier off.