# Why does Windows play a notification sound when I turn on an external light next to my laptop?

Tags: windows, usb, notifications, noise, device-mapper

This question is similar to (but the answer is not ok):

[Why does Windows 8 plays a sound when I switch on an external light?](https://superuser.com/questions/505025/why-does-windows-8-plays-a-sound-when-i-switch-on-an-external-light)

I have a large fluorescent light above my desktop, sometimes when I turned it on or off my laptop plays a notification sound but there is no message on USB's recognized or disconnected.
Is there a way to find a log of all notifications my laptop is playing?

I have Windows 11, an Aorus 15P XD, the power cord and the monitor are the only devices connected to the wall power socket, the light is embedded on the same wall... the only USBs connected to the computer are:

- USB for a powered off headset
- same headset connected for charging
- latpot base with fans
- 2 keyboards and a mouse (all wired)

Comment: Windows doesn't display any messages when a USB device is disconnected or reconnected unless it has to install a new driver. This is an exact duplicate.

Comment: "a notification sound" ... which one? device connect? device disconnect? both? something else? since this is a laptop, have you tried disconnecting the monitor and see if the issue persists?